# How can I use React-Native on CodeSpace(Github)?

Tags: react-native, codespaces, github-codespaces

I want to use React-Native on Github CodeSpace. Because in my situation(I'm a soldier so I have to use a public computer with bad specifications and that computer is reset every time I turn it on and on), I can only use cloud IDE like CodeSpace.

There is no problem to use expo in CodeSpace, but I have some problems to set developing environment for using React Native CLI on Codespace.

I followed React-native official document(Setting up the development environment), which I wrote right below.
[Link : Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&os=linux)

I want to develop android app, and the OS of CodeSpace is Linux.

According to official document, First Step is install Node 16 or newer, and Second Step is install JDK 11.
I finished this until second step.
But I can't install Android Studio on CodeSpace which is third step of official document. Because CodeSpace doesn't have GUI.
So I install android-sdk commandlinetools(I followed below link).
[Link : Install android-sdk commandlinetools](https://developer.android.com/tools)

And I type `npm run bundle`, it doesn't work....

Is there anybody who use React-Native on CodeSpace?

Comment: Hello, have you considered alternatives like renting out a Linux/mac server and using a screen share provider to access the gui? This way you could literally code anywhere with a phone that can screenshare. I do this on Android but via ssh only. Something like termux could help here.

Comment: Also here is a helpful reddit thread that talks about android development in codespace https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/11fzzjk/how_android_devs_can_use_github_codespaces/ the specific article that may help in that thread is here https://guides.codepath.com/android/installing-android-sdk-tools

Comment: @fengelhardt Thank you for your answer. It really works! Now I can install Android cmdline-tools on CodeSpace.